# Why the template version is chosen below by the compiler?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The template version is used by the compiler to calculate `t = max(a, b)` and `max(t, c)`. Any quote from the Standard supporting this is welcome.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
    std::cout << "template" << '\n';
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    return max (max(a,b), c);
}

inline int const& max (int const& a, int const& b)
{
    std::cout << "non-template" << '\n';
    return a <b ? b : a;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << max(3, 5, 7) << '\n';   
}
```

[The code prints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c685ef390a78ff1f)

```
template
template
7
```

Comment: Try forward declaring `int const& max (int const& a, int const& b)` before your 3-argument `max`?

Comment: @Yakk I know this will solve the problem. But I want to know why is this?

Comment: Overloads after the point of `template` definition are only found via ADL by the standard.  `int` is not a user defined type, so your ADL isn't working (I don't know how non-user defined type ADL works if it works at all, honestly).  Some compilers **cough** visual studio **cough** don't do this properly (not sure about 2013).

Answer (score 8):

The definition of your non-template version of `max()` is not visible at the call-site, it's defined afterwards. Either move that function above the 3-argument `max()` or add a prototype above the call-site.

```
int const& max (int const& a, int const& b);
```

Now the non-template version is chosen in both cases.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ab1417a50ecb065)

---

As for why this is the case, I believe *§3.4.1/1 [basic.lookup.unqual]* holds the answer.

> In all the cases listed in 3.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name. If no declaration is found, the program is ill-formed.

Note that argument-dependent name lookup does not apply in your case since the arguments to `max` are `int`, and not a user defined type. Only unqualified name lookup applies, hence, as quoted above, the lookup stops when the first match (the function template version of `max()`) is found.

The last sentence in the quoted section also explains why if you comment out the function template version of `max()` your code will not compile.

Comment: @TonyD That's correct, however, since primitive types do not have namespaces, there are no namespaces for ADL to search in.

Comment: Is there any explanation of why ADL shouldn't apply to`int`s? I am going to guess it doesn't apply to other built-in types as well.